# Error: Invalid JSON object

Tags: json, r, mongodb

I tried to run this query and keep having this error:

```r
install.packages(“mongolite”)
library(mongolite)

m <- mongo(db = "ionmom")
m6 <- m$aggregate('[{"$unwind":"$cdr"}, {$lookup:{from: "inventory", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as:"inventory"}},{$unwind: "$inventory"}, {"$project":{ "$project": {"cdr.duration": 1, "inventory.wearables.type":1, "inventory.wearables.status":1, "inventory.wearables.battery":1 }}}]')

# Error: Invalid JSON object: [{"$unwind":"$cdr"}, {$lookup:{from: "inventory", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as:"inventory"}},{$unwind: "$inventory"}, {"$project":{ "$project": {"cdr.duration": 1, "inventory.wearables.type":1, "inventory.wearables.status":1, "inventory.wearables.battery":1 }}}]
```

Answer (score 7):

`mongolite` uses `jsonlite` under the hood to do the JSON parsing. If you put your query through `jsonlite::fromJSON()` you'll see the issue

```
js <- '[{"$unwind":"$cdr"}, {$lookup:{from: "inventory", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as:"inventory"}},{$unwind: "$inventory"}, {"$project":{ "$project": {"cdr.duration": 1, "inventory.wearables.type":1, "inventory.wearables.status":1, "inventory.wearables.battery":1 }}}]'

jsonlite::fromJSON(js)

# Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
#                  [{"$unwind":"$cdr"}, {$lookup:{from: "inventory", loc
#                      (right here) ------^
```

This is telling you the JSON structure is invalid, because it's expecting quotes `" "` around each string

```
js <- '[{"$unwind":"$cdr"}, {"$lookup":{"from": "inventory", "localField": "_id", "foreignField": "_id", "as":"inventory"}},{"$unwind": "$inventory"}, {"$project":{ "$project": {"cdr.duration": 1, "inventory.wearables.type":1, "inventory.wearables.status":1, "inventory.wearables.battery":1 }}}]'

m$aggregate(js)

## I don't have your data ...

# Imported 0 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

Comment: I got the data to import to data frame but one problem is that the wearables are in the array of inventory collection how do I unwind the wearable array.

Comment: @HueyDucVu If you have a new/separate question you should open a new question, not ask it in the comments. Also, there are plenty of examples on here about how to un-nest lists / extract elements from lists in R

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
js <- '[{"$unwind":"$cdr"}, {"$lookup":{"from": "inventory", localField:}]'
```