# mongolite: how to perform a LIKE query?

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I want to perform a partial match query on a MongoDB in R. I've tried to specify a query that matches the [MongoDB query format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-and-as-well-as-or-conditions) like so:

```
library(mongolite)
foo <- mongo(url = "myConnectionString")
bar <- foo$find(
  query = '{"_id": /idContainsThis/}',
  fields = '{}'
)
```

But when I try this, I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid JSON object: {"_id": /idContainsThis/}
```

I can't use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351682/error-invalid-json-object) because if I put quotes round the term, the `/` is taken as a string literal, not the wildcard I need.

Does anyone know how to make this work with `mongolite`?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the regex function like this

```
query = '{"_id": { "$regex" : "idContainsThis", "$options" : "i" }}'
```

The `"$options" : "i"` is in case you want it to be case insensitive.

However I am not sure if this will work on an `_id`